# org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException

Tags: java, apache-poi

i want to read a microsoft word document i.e. .docx format using POI but getting error:

```
The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. POI only supports OLE2 Office documents
```

if anyone can help me to get rid of this??

Comment: Without code it is difficult to help. Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html about new models XSSF and HSSF.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a read through the [Converting from HSSF to the Common SS Usermodel page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html) to help you understand what you need to change.

As a general guide though, if your code was previously

```
 HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("foo.xls"));
 HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 HSSFRow r = s.getRow(0);
 System.out.println("Cell A1 is " + r.getCell(0));
```

It should instead become

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("foo.xls")); // Or foo.xlsx
 Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 Row r = s.getRow(0);
 System.out.println("Cell A1 is " + r.getCell(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which API from POI you are using, but I presume that you are using the HSSF API. Instead you should use the the XSSF API (see http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html for details). For example instead of using `Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();` use `Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Answer (score 0):

HSSF workbook will not work for higher version of excel file instead of HSSFWorkbook use XXSFWOrkbook.You can have the complete code in the below link

http://aravind-soa.blogspot.com/2017/02/how-to-import-excel-file-into-oracle.html